# How to create a sticky footer inside the LeftNav?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to create a sticky footer inside the `<LeftNav>` component, so far unsuccessfully. This is what is needs to look like:

[image]

I have tried using `position: fixed; bottom: 0` and `position: absolute; bottom: 0` on the wrapper of the search field, but when the user scrolls the list items the search field travels up. Like this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sligthly offtopic question: Which tool did you use to create the screen mockups?

Answer (score 1):

Position: fixed should work. Without more information about how you have your page setup, it's hard to be more specific. Take a look at this fiddle and see if that helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/kevinlrak/r1mpf1n8/

```
#search {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<LeftNav>` should contain two elements:

- The first one contains the items and has an `overflow-y` set to `auto` (to scroll when too long) and a javascript-set `height` of the navigation panel height minus the search field height (include paddings!)
- The second one is `position: absolute`, `bottom: 0` and `width: 100%` and contains (or is) your `#search` field

Example where `this.props.height` is set to my `window.innerHeight` on `window`'s `load` and `resize` events:

```jsx
<LeftNav>
  <div style={{overflowY: 'auto', height: (this.props.height - 50) + 'px'}}>
    {menuItems}
  </div>
  <div style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, width: '100%'}}>
    {{searchField}}
  </div>
</LeftNav>
```

Comment: How would you determine the height of the search field dynamically instead of hard coding it to 50?